# Syntax error at or near "user" when adding Postgres constraint

Tags: postgresql

I'm running Postgres 8.4.13, and trying to add a constraint to an existing table. According to [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-altertable.html), this should be possible:

```
alter table indexed_friends add constraint no_duplicate_user_friends unique (user, friend);
```

Yet when I run this I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
```

I'm confused because I'm following an unique constraint example listed in the documentation almost exactly. I can provide the table schema, but since it's complaining about a syntax error, I'm not sure that's necessary.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Ahhh... The word `user` is a reserved word in Postgres.

Surrounding it in quotes:

```
alter table indexed_friends add constraint no_duplicate_user_friends unique ("user", friend);
```

worked.

Comment: Better still, don't use reserved words as column names.  It's just a continuing series of sorrow and problems like this.

Comment: Yeah... sadly I did the initial schema in SqlAlchemy, so I didn't even realize the problem.

Answer (score -1):

For me I had not installed postgres with server. Apparently PGAdmin just administers servers. But real DB need to be with postgres and it's server.

Comment: That's true, but unrelated to a `syntax error at or near "user"` anyone is experiencing